# SQL Server CE 4.0 - default value for nvarchar column

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am struggling to find any documentation or examples how to set up a default value for a column in SQL Server CE to be an empty string for nvarchar type.

For example:

```
create table [test] (
     Col1 nvarchar(100) null default ''
)
```

creates a column with default value of ''. I've tried many different combination and none of them seems to be recognized as an empty string correctly - when using a space(0) not null they are treated just as a string value 'space(0)'. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you verify if a default value has been set? Are you checking as described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2008/04/03/dropping-defaults.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your default is set correctly as an empty string.

The most common problem I see when people have trouble with default constraints is just misunderstanding when they're used.  INSERT INTO dbo.Table(Col1) VALUES(NULL) does not trigger the default for Col1, but inserts NULL.  The default is used when the column doesn't appear at all in the insert query, or when you use the keyword DEFAULT as the column value.